# How does one identify the time consuming tasks in a SimPy simulation?

Tags: python, simpy

I would like to speed up a SimPy simulation (if possible), but I'm not sure the best way to insert timers to even see what is taking long.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend using `runsnakerun` , which uses cProfile(there are directions on runsnakerun's webpage)

Comment: I will try this out. In the meantime, I found information in the docs about the [real time environment](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topical_guides/real-time-simulations.html). It specifically states it can be used to analyze the real-time behavior of an algorithm. Any experience with this?

Comment: I dont think that does what you think it does :P ... I stand by my earlier suggestion :P

Comment: It probably doesn't since I can't wrap my brain around quite how it would work. You might be your comment in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [runsnakerun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) (or I guess snakeviz in py3x),  which uses cProfile(there are directions on runsnakerun's webpage)

basically you just run your program

```
python -m cProfile -o profile.dump my_main.py
```

then you can get a nice visual view of your profile with runsnake (or snakeviz if using py3)

```
python runsnakerun.py profile.dump
```

(note that running it in profile mode will probably slow down your code even more ... but its really just to identify slow parts)

Comment: Unfortunately `runsnakerun` is not compatible with Python 3.x; nor is it being maintained anymore. I've found `snakeviz` that is, and it is still in active development. Consider updating your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
t1 = time.time()
#code to time
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

You can use this and compare the times with all code samples you want to test

Comment: ummm while this is true for simple stuff I dont think this is going to be very helpful to the OP ... time/memory profiling `simpy` is going to take significantly more work :P)

Comment: Regardless of the code complexity, this will time it and that is what the OP has asked for @JoranBeasley. Care to clarify OP?

Comment: sympy is implemented largely in C ... please advise what parts of sympy are taking up most of the time, using this method

Comment: This is a way to look at it. It has me thinking. But @JoranBeasley is right in that gaining actionable knowledge about the methods within the `simpy` simulation using this method would take a heck of a lot of `time.time()` statements and a sophisticated system to track them all.

Comment: Alright my apologizes i'll remove the post shortly. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Don't remove the post. I am actually using both answers to get at what I need. So I think it's worth keeping here.

Comment: @JGerulskis : Hi, can't fix your typo in `t2 - t2`. (Edits must be at least 6 characters). Can you?